# How to fit TradingView Market Data widget in mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, tradingview-api

[Here](https://github.com/chinthub/Notion_Widget) is my entire repo to insert TradingView Market Data widget into my mobile device.

And here's how it looks like on PC (which is accurate and how I want it to look):
[image: PC widget]

And here's how it looks like on Mobile(Inaccurate and want to make it similar to PC):
[image: Mobile Widget]

Basically, my Mobile widget crops out the "Name" property of the table and only shows all the other properties.
Can someone please help me out? I have searched quite a few places but did not find a solution anywhere
(I tried setting the resize to True and also setting the meta-name to fit device-width but to no success)

Comment: Have you considered hiding a few value's or maybe cropping them together? The issue will persist because of the font-size and I'm assuming you don't want to make the text smaller.

Comment: I don't mind making the font size smaller but I need it to be readable. Can you help me how to change that? @Iliass Nassibane

Comment: Also.. I already have a horizontal scrollbar in this widget that shows me the values from "high" to "prev" columns, so are you sure it is because of the font size?

Comment: Yes, because there is alot of data, the table doesn't fit on the screen. What I would suggest is generating a different layout when displayed on a mobile device. Here's a great article that you can use: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/